# send() before recv()

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, recv

i have two projects: one is a client and one is a server.
lets say the server as to send 2 messages one after the other to the client.
the client code is like this:

```
while(1)
{
      recv(acceptedStr, socket);
      printf("%s\n, acceptedStr);
      *other code lines*
}
```

while the server code is like this:

```
while(1)
    {
          send(socket, "First String");
          send(socket, "Second String");
          *other code lines*
     }
```

if there is no TIME_OUT for the second send, will the recv of the client get "Second String"? or does he have to make sure that he is in a recv before the server send?

Comment: Do you expect to see a `\n` after each of the sent strings? That is not guaranteed. With a TCP connection you might receive the data with one `recv` or with ten. Only the order is ensured. Not the borders between single `send` calls. If you use UDP then the border of each datagram is fixed but you might recive them in different order.

Comment: Your send and recv call arguments are incorrect.

Comment: You probably need some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). Did you consider using [libevent](https://libevent.org/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/) ?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your question**

Yes, That is enough and your code will work. But if you want to extend it more, or if the server and the client need to be at sync at all times, do continue reading.

**Sync of server and client**

Do read this if you want synchronous operations of server and client.

I have previously worked with send and recv and one thing that I would suggest you is that you always alternate the recv and send in complementary ways. As an example

**Server:**

```
send()
recv()
send()
.
.
.
```

**Client:**

```
recv()
send()
recv()
.
.
.
```

This usually gets tiring to keep track of. (I think the return send from a entity on recv is called `ack`).

But, at some point you would like to turn the flow of events. For this, you can just send and recv some random data.

I had previously written a wrapper around send and recv for a project of mine. Feel free to check it out: https://github.com/ArenaGrenade/Simple-FTP-Server/blob/main/utils.cpp. (Its pretty well documented, so even if you did not understand my explanation you would understand the one in code.)

Let me know if you understood by marking mine as an answer. Happy to help! If you have doubts just comment below. :)

Comment: Where is your comment? @alk

Comment: I removed it. I did not met the question.

Comment: No problem! Do upvote if you find it right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, the receiving end does not need to have an `recv` active for the `send` to work.

Once a connection is established, the data is buffered by the OS network stack. And `recv` will succeed once data has arrived and `send` will succeed if the data was delivered to the network stack of the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

The client does receive the `Second String`, but it does not work as you think it should.

I created the client and server through the two official samples:[Complete Winsock Client Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code) and [Complete Winsock Server Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code)

I modified the sample so that the server only sends data and the client only receives data.

When I try to send data twice in a row, the client will receive the following content:

[image]

[image]

You can see that the client does receive `Second String`, but because you keep sending these two data, it will cause problems in the picture.

Because the data is being sent continuously, the client will also receive the data sent multiple times at one time, and save them to the same buffer, although only part of it is displayed (because it is truncated by'\0'), but It can be seen from the size of the buffer that the data sent multiple times is received at one time.And the content received later will be unpredictable